# If half a large creature's body falls on two squares, what happens?

Tags: dnd-4e, creature-size, battle-map, falling

In our game session, a Minotaur Warden knocked a large Mooncalf out of the air onto the edge of a cliff.

Half of the creature is on the edge and the other half is over the side.
The left 2 squares are over ground and the other 2 are over the air.

Does the creature fall, can the large creature act normally?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The creature will remain standing standing as long as it has 1 square of itself still on land.

The rules on [falling](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=174) are on page 209 of the *Rules Compendium*:

> On the creature's next turn, it must either move to an unoccupied space that is at least as large as it is or squeeze if it wants to remain on the edge of the drop.